# Disable the admin bar for all users except admin

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed WordPress and BudyPress. I want to disable the admin bar which appears on the top for all users.

Can somebody tell me how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function is_current_user_administrator() {
    global $current_user;

    return !in_array( 'administrator', $current_user->roles );
}

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'is_current_user_administrator' );
```

Comment: The above should go either into a plugin or your theme's _functions.php_ file.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file, you can add one of the following code snippets to get the indicated results:

// Only display to administrators

```
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

 function remove_admin_bar() {
     if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert the following code to the end of functions.php file and click Update File Button to save the changes:**

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );